Фазы цикла события pending callbacks и poll в node.js
Многие наверное читали документацию node.js, в том числе и раздел event loop.
Вопрос следующего характера: Какие функции обратного вызова вызываются на стадии poll, а какие на pending callbacks (нужны конкретные примеры)?

Учитывайте что пример с ошибкой TCP это прям единичный пример (в исходном коде libuv туда много что отправляется):

This phase executes callbacks for some system operations such as types of TCP errors. For example if a TCP socket receives ECONNREFUSED when attempting to connect, some *nix systems want to wait to report the error. This will be queued to execute in the pending callbacks phase.

